# Want to Write a Program that Will Switch Networks (Wireless)

Tags: macos, networking, network-programming

I have two units on my property, one residence, other is now an office. I have an Airport Extreme in each place and they are bridged. Sadly, the basic software in the devices (iPads, phone, laptop) do a truly awful job of deciding when to change networks. What really sucks about this is I do some calling sometimes, and the call will drop even though the other network is there and has a great signal.

I posted on the Apple Discussion Forums, and a dude gave me a good answer, but it sounds like their reasoning is still not going to produce a good result.

I want to write a program that does this:

1. The minute it sees a drop in the signal, it looks for the other network.
2. Then it starts to monitor the *ratio* of signal between the two.
3. Soon as it favors one over the other by more than a marginal amount, it changes.

I hope this is not seen as an admin question. This is a programming question. Has anyone any experience with the frameworks that Apple's developer tools would have for this?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use the Apple80211 private framework. There's no official documentation (since it's private), but there is good progress on reverse engineering it. See [here](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/AppleEightOhTwoEleven) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/). A lot of the information out there is actually from the iOS version, but the two are similar enough to use information from one on the other.

Comment: It seems like an easy problem, but believe me, it's not. With a simple switching algorithm your program might keep changing networks, effetively ping-ponging for quite some time. Even worse, wifi networks need several seconds for the client association to complete. Search for 'wifi handover' or something similar to have a deeper understanding. On a different note, on Linux you can set 'sensitivity' of a wireless interface - basically telling the HW the lowest signal level for which it remains associated to the AP. Perhaps something similar exists on OS X.

Comment: Dude, thanks for the comments. I am not saying it's a simple problem, I am saying that for my requirements, it's pretty simple, because when I go to my backhouse I have like 5 bars there and 1 from the other. That's not going to cause ping-ponging. Also, what the post on the apple discussions said was that the existing algorithm only considers another network when its connection has basically gone away. That's pretty stupid.